# K nearest neighbour validation performance

Tags: classification, data-mining, spss, nearest-neighbor

I am using knn to do classification for a telecom problem. I splitted my data into 70% training and 30% validation. While the knn classifier is able to catch over 80% in 2 deciles in training, its performance in validation sample is as good as random 45 degree line. I am surprised how does KNN work that the model performance in training and validation are so different.

Any pointers ?

Comment: Did you split randomly, or first 70% vs. last 30%? If your data is ordered, this can screw you badly.

Comment: Its the spss random split in the partition node that I gave 70% and 30%. Believe that is random.

Answer (score 1):

Reasonable pointers are hardly possible without more details. The behavior of your KNN depends on several aspects:

- The parameter `K` defining the neighbors. If it is set to `K=1`, for example, you will get no training error at all, this showing that the consideration of training-to-validation-error may not be justified.
- The parameter `K` is often found using [cross validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29). I would suggest you to do this as well.
- The distance metric. Which function are you using, are there different units, length scales, etc.?
- The noise of your data, the size of your data ... -- there simply exist data sets which are hard to describe.

By the way: can you tell what kind of data you want to describe, and, if possible, also provide some examples or show some scatter plot (data and your result)?

Comment: Thats right. But @davidhigh my problem is absolute random 45 degree line. I would have understood if my validation would have fallen drastically also. But an absolute random line tells me something is wrong somewhere. I am trying to predict an upgrade of a user service from x to y. I used both euclidean and city metric ( options given in spss ). The data has an event rate of 10.4%. There are .2Mn rows.

Comment: BTW..why would I get no error if k=1 ? How do i find k with cross validation ?? enlighten me please.

Comment: @ayushbiyani: I agree, an absolutely random line obviously seems wrong. `K=1` means that you draw some region around each data point and classify it with the type of the data point itself, thus the training error becomes zero. Regarding cross-validationm read the link to Wikipedia above.

Comment: Thats what. what do you suggest me to do/try ? Basically a 45 degree line means that my 30% points are so separate from the 70% that none of the points are getting classified correctly even by mistake ? aint it ?

Comment: It's hard to tell from the far. Myself I would probably either validate the KNN-routine using some easy datasets, or write my own program to reproduce/disprove the SSPS results (basic KNN is rather simple) ... we can approach this together if you upload some sample data.

Comment: @ayushbiyani so which values of `k` did you try? Training error with `k=1` can be zero unless you have duplicates with different classification. Often, you may want to choose `k` one less on the real data than on the training; depending on the exact implementation.

Comment: I have tried using different K values ( 3, 5, 9, 13, 21, 25, 29, 31). Am I able to convey my problem ? My problem is getting a random 45 degree line in validation. That shouldnt be the case. I am also interested in discussing with you all as to when would I see that case. Wat does it mean mathematically and business way.